# How to compute a weighted mean as a measure of central tendency?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, data-analysis

Imagine I have data points in triplicates, as follows
$$
L=\begin{pmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13}\\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23}\\
& \vdots &\\
p_{n1} & p_{n2} & p_{n3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
What is the best way to filter this data, so that I remove outliers and end up with a vector of best-fit values
$$
\tilde{L}=(\tilde{p}_1,\tilde{p}_2,\cdots,\tilde{p}_n)
$$
**Thoughts:** For example, if I have the plot

[image]

I could naturally take the mean of these values (in blue)

[image]

but clearly, at $n=5$ I have a potential outlier, which could be removed for a better fit. What would be the ideal technique to **assign a weighted mean to each triplicate based on the overall dataset**, possibly based on the average standard deviation between triplicates? I have heard about [Cook's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance), but I am not too sure how to apply it here.

Any ideas?